# C# WinForm Tab not working after Leave event

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I'm using WinForm with .Net 4.0. Trying to show password while cursor is on text box.

```
    private void txtUserPW_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.txtUserPW.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
    }

    private void txtUserPW_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.txtUserPW.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
    }
```

Problem: When pressing TAB on text box it is not moving to next control.

Comment: Detect in the KeyPress event if its a TAB and programmatically set Focus to next control...

Comment: Make sure `AcceptsTab` is set to `False`.

Comment: won't that be an over kill? shouldn't WinForm handle it?

Comment: @JimSimson AcceptTab is already set to False.

Comment: That property is a "difficult" one, it requires Winforms to recreate the native Windows control to use different style flags in the underlying CreateWindowEx() call.  You can tell by looking closely, note how it flickers when you press Tab.  That has side-effects, the destruction of the old control window messes up focus.  You have to delay the assignment, use  this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { this.textBox2.UseSystemPasswordChar = false; }));